# Use a Card Reader to input data into an Excel spreadsheet that is running in the background

Tags: excel, usb

I currently am collecting data from a large quantity of participants, all of whom have a badge that is scanned at the point of entry; logging ID, date/time etc...  This is all tracked on a laptop running Windows 10 / Excel.
The issue here is that the laptop currently must only be devoted to this task.  The ideal scenario would be that the card reader (usb peripheral) would input data into the spreadsheet as a background process.
Is there a way to route a USB peripheral to a sole application, even if that application is not in the foreground?

Cheers, and thank you!

Comment: The answer totally depends on your device. What is it? (and what kind of card?) Some devices emulate keyboard input, others have their own transfer methods.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer - The device acts as a keyboard and is a HID OmniKey 5427.  Due to my Excel formatting it needs to stay as a Keyboard input.

Comment: What else are you planning on using the computer for?  Something involving the keyboard, I assume?

Comment: Correct -  I am running a web-app and using the keyboard for participant interface.  Obviously I could switch to the excel spreadsheet prior to having them badge, and switch back out to the web app, but that would hinder the process to the point where I would not be able to complete some of the other necessary tasks.